# MYSQL Trigger to update table that is based on two other tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, triggers

I've created a table name 'combined_data' using data from two tables 'store_data' and 'hd_data'. The two tables share a common column which I used to link the data when creating the new table and that is 'store_num'. What happens is when a user submits information to 'store_data' I want info from that submit such as store_num, store_name, etc to move into the 'combined_data' table as well as pull information from the 'hd_data' that pertains to the particular store_num entered such as region, division etc. Trying to come up with the structure to do this, I can fill in table names and column names just fine. Just curious if this is doable or if another solution should be sought out?

Comment: Is there a reason, such as efficiency, that you're not using views for this?

Comment: I've got some decent experience with database work but I'm not expert by any means, if there are alternatives to what I've proposed, I'm open to anything

Answer (score 0):

This is a common situation when saving data and requires to be split into 2 or more different repositories. I would create a stored procedure, and pass everything into a transaction, so if at any time something fails, it would roll back, and you would have consistency between your tables.

However, yes you can also do it with a trigger on insert of data on either store_data, or hd_data, if you would like to keep it simple.

Comment: The grand scope of this is when someone searches for a store by number, division, region etc it will pull up the most recent entry to that store or multiple stores if they search by division, etc. Currently if you search by store number it will show you the most recent entry, but thats based off selecting the most recent entry based on store_num which is in the store_data table, the other search possiblities, region, division etc are within the 'hd_data' table so when a user searches by those means I don't know how to show the reports for all stores listed.

Comment: The tables have to have an ID, which is used to link the tables together (Primary, and foreign keys). Can't you use this to obtain the store ID, and then get what data is necessary from all the tables present?